# Unable to click on available date using selenium ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm not able to click on available date in the calendar. Past dates are greyed out so trying to get today's date and click on it. I have tried execute script, click() and perform() but none of them worked.

```
today_date =  Date.today.strftime('%d')
element = @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//td[contains(@class,\"CalendarDay__default\")][contains(@aria-label, '#{today_date}')]")
#@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click;", element )
@driver.action.move_to(ele).click(ele).perform
```

I also tried loop but td element is not displayed as some of elements are greyed out. Not sure how to select displayed elements?

```
today_date=  Date.today.strftime('%d')
date_picker= @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//*[contains(@class,'SingleDatePicker_picker')]")
columns=date_picker.find_elements(:tag_name, "td")
calendar_date=columns.map(&:text).reject(&:empty?)
columns.each do |col|
  # This returns true  
  puts "include date: #{calendar_date.include?today_date}"

  if calendar_date.include?today_date
    # Elemement is not displayed
    puts "td displayed: #{col.displayed?}"
    # Not clickable
   col.click
  end
end
```

Please find html below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you just do send keys in that input box. You will have to generate today's date

Comment: Is it in an iframe? Please share the full html and all your relevant code so that we may reproduce this.

Comment: @cruisepandey I have to select date. send keys doesn't work.

Comment: @C.Peck I don't think so I tried to find element by tag_name iframe and it didn't return any output. I hope updated code image helps..thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Perhaps you have to use the click in the parent of that element.

Comment: @Rajagopalan It's throwing timeout error as it keeps on waiting for element to be displayed but there is no attributes returning  for "col" element.  Did you mean I try. to click parent of td? Can you pls post an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to know what will work exactly without being able to work with the actual html, but my guess is that the first thing that is getting matched by that locator is not what you want. Try with this:

```
element = browser.td(aria_label: Time.now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y"))
```

Or you can select the first non-disabled element regardless of date:

```
element = browser.td(aria_disabled: 'false')
```

Edit: just realized your code is Selenium even though the label is Watir. The XPath equivalent to the above are:

```
".//td[@aria-label=#{Time.now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")}]"    
".//td[@aria-disabled='false']"
```

Comment: First Xpath worked for me..Can't thank you enough for helping. I was stuck with issue for a while now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, Titus, I have included the WATIR tag so that he could get the help. I used to add the WATIR tag for question which is of Ruby Selenium Binding. I add this for two purpose, One is, People get the help and another reason is, People will come to know the WATIR wrapper as well. It is not a problem for you , eh?

Comment: @Rajagopalan if it isn't about Watir, it shouldn't have the watir tag added. I'll look into setting up an alert for general Selenium Ruby questions so I can get a ping about those as well.